# Show previous result until current is loaded for Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typehead

I am using Twitter Bootstrap's typehead for search suggestions. When a key is pressed any previously loaded results disappear while new results are loaded by AJAX.

This is the code I am using:

```
el.typeahead(
        { highlight: true },
        {
            limit: 10,
            name: type,
            source: ob.typheadSource,
            templates: { suggestion: ob.typeheadSuggeestion }
        }
    );
```

The source property is a function which loads data via AJAX and the templates property provides another function to handle the result of that AJAX call.

Is there a way to leave the previous result, until the new request has been completed and can be inserted without causing a flicker?

Comment: Could you not place a loading mask over the results until a successful callback has been executed?

Comment: I don't know how that would be done. The templates property has a pending option, but it still causes a flicker.